# Find the pairs of integers that sum to N

Tags: python, beginner, k-sum

Can it be made faster, and I am a newbie to complexity but I'm pretty sure the average case for this would be O(n). Am I wrong?
Output for the first list should be: (1,9), (2,8), (5,5), (-11,21)

The program finds pairs of an array whose sum is equal to ten.

```
#find pairs of an array whose sum is equal to ten
#bonus do it im linear time

list1 = [1,1,2,1,9,9,5,5,2,3,745,8,1,-11,21]
list2 = [1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,2,8,8,8,2,2,0,0,0]
list3 = ["dog", "cat", "penguin", 9, 1]
list4 = []

def find_pairs_sum_n(list1, n):
    set1 = set(list1)
    history = set()

    if not list1:
        print("list is empty")
        raise StopIteration
    if not all(isinstance(n, int) for n in list1):
        print("list must contain only integers")
        raise StopIteration

    for x in set1:
        history.add(x)
        if (n - x) in set1 and (n-x) not in history:
            yield (x, n - x)

        elif x == n/2 and list1.count(n/2) > 1:
            yield (int(n/2), int(n/2))


x = find_pairs_sum_n(list1, 10)
for i in x:
    print(i)

y = find_pairs_sum_n(list2, 10)
for i in y:
    print(i)

z = find_pairs_sum_n(list3, 10)
print(next(z))

w = find_pairs_sum_n(list4, 10)
print(next(w))
```

Comment: What's the problem description, was this from a book? A programming challenge?

Comment: @Mast, it's a question I got off a list of interview questions. No book, not really a challenge, just a puzzle I wanted to work on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In no particular order, a few suggestions to make the code more Pythonic.

#### `return` from generator

You do not need to `raise StopIteration` in a generator, you can simply return. So this:

```
if not list1:
    print("list is empty")
    raise StopIteration
if ...
```

Could have been a bit simpler as:

```
if not list1:
    print("list is empty")
elif ...
```

#### Use an `Exception` for exceptions

It is generally bad practice to put `prints` into your computation routines.  Instead consider using exceptions.

```
if not list1:
    raise ValueError("list is empty")
```

Then catch the exception like:

```
try:
    for j in find_pairs_sum_n(l, 10):
        print(j)
except ValueError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

#### You don't need history

Since the values you are evaluating are already unique by putting them into a `set()`, you don't need history.  Instead, only do the evaluation for numbers which are < 1/2 of `n`.

#### Mid value check only once

For the mid-value check I suggest you do it only once (ie, not in the loop).  Additionally if you use `collections.Counter` instead of the `set()` you don't need to do the `list.count()` because you already have the counts.

#### Consider using a generator expression

Now that we have simplified the loop somewhat, it can be pretty cleanly written as a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
yield from ((x, n-x) for x in values if x <= threshold and (n - x) in values)
```

#### Full code listing

```
from collections import Counter

def find_pairs_sum_n(values, n):
    values = Counter(values)
    non_ints = {x for x in values if not isinstance(x, int)}

    if non_ints:
        raise ValueError(
            "Found non-integers in values: {}".format(non_ints))

    threshold, n_odd = divmod(n, 2)
    if not n_odd:
        if values[threshold] > 1:
            yield threshold, threshold
        threshold -= 1

    yield from (
        (x, n-x) for x in values if x <= threshold and (n - x) in values)


list1 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 5, 5, 2, 3, 745, 8, 1, -11, 21]
list2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]
list3 = ["dog", "cat", "penguin", 9, 1]
list4 = []

for l in (list1, list2, list3, list4):
    try:
        for j in find_pairs_sum_n(l, 10):
            print(j)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(exc)
    print('---')
```

#### Results:

```
(5, 5)
(1, 9)
(2, 8)
(-11, 21)
---
(1, 9)
(2, 8)
(4, 6)
---
Found non-integers in values: {'dog', 'penguin', 'cat'}
---
---
```